# Bit parity code for odd number of bits

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit, parity

I am trying to find the parity of a bitstring so that it returns 1 if x has an odd # of 0's.
I can only use basic bitwise operations and what I have so far passes most of the tests, but I'm wondering 2 things:

1. Why does x ^ (x + ~1) work?  I stumbled upon this, but it seems to give you 1 if there are an odd number of bits and something else if even.  Like 7^6 = 1 because 7 = 0b0111
2. Is this the right direction of problem solving for this?  I'm assuming my problem is stemming from the first operation, specifically (x + ~1) because it would overflow certain 2's complement numbers. Thanks

Code:

```
int bitParity(int x) {
    int first = x ^ (x + ~1);
    int second = first ^ 1; // if first XOR gave 1 you'll return 0 here
    int result = !!second;
return result;
}
```

Comment: Where did you find that algorithm?

Comment: don't use `int`, there will be overflow and this then is undefined behavior. Use `unsigned` and `1u` instead, here the wrap around is well defined.

Comment: This algorithm does not work. It returns 1 for all values between 0 and 255.

Comment: I took odd bit binary numbers and XOR'd, AND'd, and OR'd them with themselves minus 1 and XOR was the only one that gave something useful (or so I thought).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bitParity - Finding odd number of bits in an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133279/bitparity-finding-odd-number-of-bits-in-an-integer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use actual counting rather than bit-level hacks that exploit the representation of the numbers, that would both feel safer and be more clean and easy to understand. Probably slower, of course, but that's a quite nice trade-off especially when one doesn't know anything about the performance expectations.

Do to this, just write code to count the number of 1 bits, the most straight-forward solution generally boils down to a loop.

**UPDATE:** Given the (weird and annoying) limitations, my response would probably be to [unwind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding) the loop given in the ["naive"](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ParityNaive) solution on the [bithacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) page. That wouldn't be pretty, but then I could go do something useful. :)

Comment: I certainly would use a loop to easily count each bit or even just XOR all the bits together, but for this assignment, I'm not allowed to use control structures.  Just | ^ & >> << ~ + !   So, your response was my immediate reaction to this, but no dice.

Comment: I've taken a previously written code for bit counting and just AND'd the result with 0x1 to see if there are an odd number of bits or not.  However, I did the bitCount(int x) algorithm via brute force; checked each bit with 
     !!(x & (1<<bit#))
This isn't good enough for me at the moment, but the bit parity problem has been solved by this for now.

Answer (score 4):

Your parity function doesn't actually work as far as I can tell - it seems to get the answer right about half of the time, which is about as good as returning a random result (or even just returning 0 or 1 all the time).

There are several bit level hacks which *do* actually work at: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ParityNaive - you probably want to look at the last one of these: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ParityParallel

Comment: I realize my full code doesn't work, but the x ^ (x-1) seemed to give answers that made sense for the values I tried.  If you're correct, then I should just dump that and start over.

Comment: Just try the input values 0, 1, 2 and 3 and you will see that it is not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

Bit parity may be done like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int parity(unsigned int x) {
    int parity=0;
    while (x > 0) {
       parity = (parity + (x & 1)) % 2;
       x >>= 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        printf("%d\t%s\n", i, parity(i)?"odd":"even");
    }
}
```